# How to select second div element in XPath?

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to select the `div` that's highlighted with the blue bar:

[image]

It's the second `div` on the page that contains the text `"All"`, so my attempt is as follows:

```
all_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(., 'All')][2]")
```

For some reason, when I run my program, this selects the `div` that's highlighted in yellow.  I've tried using `string()` and `text()` in place of a period within the `contains()` section, but it yields the same result.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
//div[contains(., 'All')][2]
```

with

```
(//div[contains(., 'All')])[2]
```

to select the second such `div` overall rather than restricting such `div` elements to be in the second child position.

You might further tighten the predicate to use string equality rather than substring containment (to avoid matching `<div>All good men</div>`, for example), if your data is truly as shown:

```
(//div[.='All'])[2]
```

Comment: The second bit of code you suggested, `(//div[.='All'])[2]`, worked perfectly.  Strangely, `(//div[contains(., 'All')])[2]` selected "Bronze" instead of "All".  The HTML containing "Bronze" is identical in structure to the code shown above for "Platinum".  The `div` that contains "Bronze" (within a `span`) is located immediately below the `div` that contains "All".

Comment: Yes, be aware that the string value of ancestor `div` elements will also contain `All` in `//div[contains(., 'All')]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try being more strict with your selection by adding a condition:

```
all_buttons = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
          "//class[contains(@class, 'filter-option selected') and contains(text(), 'All')]")
```

Now, for debugging check the size of returned list:

```
print(len(all_buttons))
```

If the 'All' buttons list size received according to the DOM, you should do fine.

Comment: That would probably work, except that it's only 'filter-option selected' if I haven't clicked on one of the other filters yet.  "All" happens to be the default case, so my first attempt at a workaround was to simply grab data from the "All" category first, before looping through the rest of the filters.